# I need help to sort by numeric in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, numeric

i have this problem to my wordpress theme but team points its with Custom field how can i sort this automatically by numeric value?

here is the link for demo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3neX.png

i want to sort automatically by numeric value.

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean inside the Wordpress Loop, take a look at WP_Query -> order_by

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: thanks bro but its not loop

look demo

http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/6317/3873523e48ed469da6a435f.png

i want to sort list by custom field

Comment: You could store all the the content into an array like `array('barca'=>'48','real-madrid' => '43')`, then order the array based on the values, and then echo the array though an foreach loop. I think that's the only way to do it

Comment: but my code is place1,place1-points and place2,place2-points and more